# What are some good resources to practice logical puzzle-solving?

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, lateral-thinking, puzzle-creation

I currently own this book called "Algorithmic Puzzles" by Anany and Maria Levitin, and I am having a hard time getting through the higher level problems.

I have always been interested in logical reasoning and puzzle-solving, and I am curious if there are **any resources out there** (ie *websites, youtube channels, books* etc) that could help me develop my problem solving skills.

Thanks,

Comment: I would recommend: [A collection of Puzzling Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/a-collection-of-puzzling-tools) hosted by Puzzling.SE itself.

Comment: Hi JonMark, thanks for the link! However, I was looking more for a "tutorial-like" webpage, rather than a collection of puzzle-solving tool resources.

Comment: there's some sudoku videos here: https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+solve+sudoku&qpvt=how+to+solve+sudoku&FORM=VDRE